# How to bind data to telerik muticolumn combo box?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I'm trying to add a dataset into it for binding but i couldn't do it cause i get some errors that lead me to undo everything that i had done

i read telerik site and i studied their program too but it didn't help at all 
in their site this was the code for binding

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    NwindDataSet nwindDataSet = new NwindDataSet();
    CustomersTableAdapter customersTableAdapter = new CustomersTableAdapter();
    customersTableAdapter.Fill(nwindDataSet.Customers);
    this.radMultiColumnComboBox1.DataSource = nwindDataSet.Customers;
    foreach (GridViewDataColumn column in this.radMultiColumnComboBox1.MultiColumnComboBoxElement.Columns)
    {
        column.BestFit();
    }
}

void SetUpGrid()
{
    RadGridView gridViewControl = this.radMultiColumnComboBox1.EditorControl;
    gridViewControl.MasterTemplate.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    gridViewControl.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("CustomerID"));
    gridViewControl.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("ContactName"));
    gridViewControl.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("ContactTitle"));
    gridViewControl.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("Country"));
    gridViewControl.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("Phone"));
}
```

is this code enough?

can someone pls help me with it

Comment: Are you calling `SetUpGrid()` anywhere?  In the code above you aren't calling that method.

Comment: @jaredbaszler some lines in code above won't work

Comment: You can't just copy and paste code from an example on Telerik's website and expect it to work.  The example you've given above is just a small part of how data binding works but you still need a basic understanding of initializing objects and making methods calls for the code above to work.  If you aren't even calling `SetUpGrid()` anywhere then you have much bigger problems to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the programatically way to do it. If you have a bindingsource you can bind it with a pair of clicks, if not you can do it manual passing the values to the DatSource property

[image]

BUT, if you wanna add it to a gridview you can do it using the editor of RadGridView, and bind it in the same way as described above

[image]

Seems that you don't have clear how do it programatically, so I recomend you the easy way: do it with the RadMultiColumnBox Task (1st image) or RadGridViewEditor (2nd image), depend if you need it in a grid

Comment: Both of you need to give credit to your above posts - both of these posts just come from [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/multicolumncombobox-databinding.html).

Comment: Credits goes to the same page that he is referring, not to me @jaredbaszler

Comment: That's exactly my point @Radolfo - both of you are posting code and images from the same page but neither of you cite the source.  So I simply cited it for you.

Comment: If you are adding a List of objects remember to set DisplayMember to the property that you want to show, for example, if Person is your object set DisplayMember = name (supposing that name is a string property of Person). Also set ValueMember to the value you want to take when you select the item, maybe you need the id, the name, or anything else. DisplayMember as it says, is for Display only @mojy

Comment: You can do it programatically in this way: radMultiColumnComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"; 
radMultiColumnComboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
OR you can do it visually in the properties of comboBox, usually located at the right of VS @mojy

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest looking in the column documentation: [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-gridviewmulticomboboxcolumn.html)